# Однозначно правильные ответы - не смешно ли?

Tags: обсуждение, вопросы, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

"чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ".

Если вы знаете что ответ есть, и знаете что он однозначный,
то зачем вообще вопрос задавать?

Особенно учитывая, что нельзя задавать вопросы на опросы мнений...

Answer (score 8):

Насколько я понимаю, речь не столько о существовании единственного верного решения, сколько о возможности определить, является ли конкретное решение верным, работающим.

Например, вопросы о том, как реализовать какой-то алгоритм на языке программирования Х, будь это сортировка массива, организация карусели с картинками или виртуализация сервера. Проблемы таких вопросов можно воспроизвести (это строгое требование к вопросу), а решения можно проверить.

Контрпример: вопрос о том, что автору выбрать — язык А или язык Б. Верность ответов проверяется лонгитюдным экспериментом: если автор выбрал язык А, прошло 40 лет и он несчастен и одинок, то ответ был неверным. Вполне возможно, что язык Б привел бы к тому же результату.

Если об ответе на вопрос нельзя точно утверждать, что он является или не является решением, хотя бы частичным — то ценность этого вопроса и ответа невысока для будущих читателей. Поэтому такие вопросы не входят в тематику сайта.

Answer (score 3):

> Если вы знаете что ответ есть, и знаете что он однозначный, то зачем вообще вопрос задавать?

Задавая вопрос, вы можете не знать, что есть однозначный ответ. И что ответ вообще есть.

- Если ответ есть - на вопрос ответят.
- Если окажется, что ответа нет, или однозначного ответа нет - вам про это напишут, и вопрос закроют.

Comment: Окей, наглядный контрпример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452712

Comment: @hse5yzdx, и в чем же контрпример? На этот вопрос нет однозначного ответа, вот его и закрыли. Все логично.

Comment: @hse5yzdx вопрос по ссылке стоило бы просто закрыть с другой причиной. он не имеет прямого отношения к программированию или администрированию -> оффтопик на этом сайте. то, что его закрыли как "опросник" - показатель лени или неопытности закрывших.

Comment: @hse5yzdx: нецензурная лексика — это скорый поезд в долгий бан. А ещё создается впечатление, как будто вы школьник.

Comment: Использованная лексика не являлась нецензурной, пруфлинк - http://ponedelnik.info/society/chetyre-maternykh-slova-zachem-gosduma-zapretila-mat

Comment: @hse5yzdx нецензурной *или* оскорбительной. кстати, отсылки к госдуме на SO не работают, это не российский сайт.

Comment: @hse5yzdx, оскорбительная лексика != мат.

Comment: ох, прошу у Бога прощения, если применённая к нему спецификация была для него оскорбительной. Вы же не приняли это на свой счёт? Или признаёте что кругом неправы?

Comment: @hse5yzdx вы сейчас к кому обращаетесь?

Comment: так вы вдвоем неправы. даже несмотря на то, что Вас двое, а я один

Answer (score 2):

Смешно конечно. Давно уже пора стать мужиком и ввести квантовые правила.

1. Запутанность. Правильный ответ приходит только на вопрос двухлетней давности из-за того что в новом вопросе кто-то оставил комментарий.
2. Принцип неопределенности. Нельзя просто так взять и одновременно измерить правильность ответа и количество голосов на нем.
3. Галочка Шредингера. С вероятностью 50 на 50 либо красная либо зеленая. Принят и не принят. Срабатывает во время наблюдения(Загрузки вопроса)

Comment: Особенно хорошо про *время наблюдения* -)

Answer (score 1):

Попробую ответить на примере двух вопросов со схожим смыслом. (Сразу оговорюсь, что это вопросы "не по теме" и приведены только для примера).

**Вопрос 1:**

Есть две прямые, `y(x) = 3 + x` и `y(x) = 5*x - 1`. В какой точке эти прямые пересекутся.

**Вопрос 2:**

Есть две прямые, `y(x) = 3 + x` и `y(x) = 5*x - 1`. Подскажите самый лучший способ для нахожедения точки пересечения этих прямых.

Очевидно, что вопрос #1 имеет решение, и ответ на него **однозначен** (конкретная точка с вполне определенными координатами). Кроме того, каждый предложенный ответ может быть либо *однозначно* правильным, либо *однозначно* ошибочным.

Что же касается вопроса #2, то на него можно дать несколько ответов, каждый из которых будет одновременно и правильным и неправильным, ведь критерии превосходства одного способа над другим не заданы. Поэтому, в данном случае **нельзя** говорить об однозначно *правильном* ответе.

**UPD:**

[Пример вопроса *с однозначно правильным ответом*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/435546/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82-use-strict).

[Пример вопроса без *однозначно правильного ответа*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/452756/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0).

Comment: то есть я правильно понял, что этот сайт для проведения вычислений и бесплатного подряда других людей на мелкие работы (с очевидными решениями, вся проблема которых в вычислительной сложности)?

Comment: Нет, вы не правильно поняли. Я специально сказал, что примеры "не по теме".

Comment: очень жаль, что Ваш ответ недоходчив.

Comment: Серьезно считаете, что вопрос #2 не достоин ответов (и должен быть уничтожен)?

Comment: @avp, вопрос #2 - это типичный опросник. В текущей постановке он не конкретен и действительно должен быть уничножен.

Comment: Может лучше уничтожить это (и еще несколько других) правило?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev опросник - это "что лучше, windows или linux". вопрос из примера - не опросник.

Comment: @avp, вот тут (http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) есть пункт "_любой ответ одинаково правильный_", который и подходит к примеру #2. Если вам не нравится этот пункт, можете смело выносить предложение о его удаленни.

Comment: @PashaPash, даже если вопрос #2 не является опросником, на него все равно нельзя дать _однозначно правильного_ ответа.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev на него можно дать однозначно правильный ответ - привести *любой* способ, который можно было бы использовать. Опросник - это "подскажите самый *лучший* способ сделать что-то".

Comment: @DmitriySimushev в правилах написано не "однозначный ответ" (ровно один ответ) а "однозначно правильный ответ" (два разных ответа, оба из которых решают проблему, но по разному) - это две большие разницы.

Comment: @PashaPash, вы правы, подправил ответ.

Comment: На мой взгляд, оба ваших примера - хорошие вопросы. Суть не в одном истинно верном ответе, а в проверяемости и верифицируемости каждого ответа. Подробнее: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1368/181472