# Причины закрытия — "Вопрос-Опросник" vs "Однозначно верный ответ"

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

На данный момент в списке причин закрытия есть две достаточно близких по формулировке:

> Не по теме, потому что… →
> Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском.
>
> Для получения ответа, перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ.

и

> Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ
>
> Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях. Для получения ответа перефразируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы на него можно было дать однозначно правильный ответ, либо удалите вопрос вовсе.

Формулировка причин практически совпадает. Я не могу придумать вопроса, который попал бы под первую причину, и не попал бы под вторую. И наоборот.

Есть ли между ними разница? Если есть, то в чем она?

Comment: Я не вижу разницы и обычно стараюсь использовать причину про «однозначно правильный ответ».

Comment: @NickVolynkin я тоже. может быть стоит устранить причину про "опросник" и заменить ее на "не имеет отношения к программированию или системному администрированию"? а то надоедает набирать :)

Comment: поддерживаю. Можно над формулировкой ещё поработать. Ссылка на справку нужна точно.

Comment: @PashaPash ваистену отличное предложение! Я бы еще ссылку на описание тематики добавил, вроде было такое.

Comment: @NickVolynkin да. Большинство из закрывающих вопросы не заходят на мету. Тыкают в наиболее подходящую причину, или в ту, в которую тыкнули до них. Поэтому формулировка должна быть такая, чтобы они не учитывались и почти всегда выбирали нормальную причину закрытия.

Comment: Я могу ошибаться, но вроде бы NicolasChabanovsky упоминал, что вышестоящие админы не очень поощряют широкий ассортимент причин закрытия, хотя редактирование списка причин вроде бы ничего не стоит.

Comment: @Nofate тем более, нет смысла держать лишнюю причину. на английском SO причина "опросник" более четко сформулирована. и явно отличается от primarily opinion-based. и там аж две недостающих у нас причины для закрытия - "не программирование" и "совсем оффтопик".

Comment: @PashaPash рано или поздно нам точно нужно будет пересмотреть набор причин закрытия.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально [эти причины задумывались](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/545/) для подсказки участникам, что они используют сайт неправильно одним из двух способов:

1. Непонятна суть.
2. Всеобъемлющий.

В первом случае, следует запросить у автора уточнение подробностей вопроса, во втором, описать проблему более конкретно. На мой взгляд, «закрывающий комментарий» выглядит достаточно подробно и отражает то, что мы запрашиваем у автора.

Буду рад выслушать конкретные предложения по улучшению формулировок закрытия вопросов.

**Обновление**

Действительно, указанные вами причины закрытия похожи как в формулировке, так и по смыслу.

Зачем добавлять похожие причины закрытия?

Добавляя причину закрытия я рассуждал следующим образом.

- Если участник видит вопрос-опросник, то он постарается найти наиболее подходящую причину закрытия вопроса, которая в будущем будет видна автору вопроса.
- Если нет точно описывающей причины закрытия вопроса, то, скорее всего, участник выберет наиболее подходящую, которой в большинстве случаев будет «всеобъемлющий вопрос». В таком случае автор не получит важной информации – что именно следует сделать, чтобы вопрос соответствовал правилам сообщества.
- Зачастую, слишком общими причинами закрытия начинают злоупотреблять.

Таким образом, на мой взгляд, следует оставить одну общую причину «всеобъемлющий вопрос», и добавить набор под-причин, наиболее точно описывающих самые частые неправильные способы использования сайта.

---

Связанные вопросы:

- [Требование однозначности ответа](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1606/).
- [Однозначно правильные ответы - не смешно ли?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1364/).
- [Уточнить перевод для “too broad” и “unclear what you're asking” причин закрытия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499/)

Comment: "необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса" и "необходимо конкретизировать вопрос" - это две другие причины (#3 и #4 в текущем списке). Я же спрашивал про " не по теме, потому что…/Вопросы-опросники запрещены на Stack Overflow на русском." и " необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ" (#2.1 и #5). Они оба соответствуют английскому primarily opinion-based.