# Уточнить перевод для "too broad" и "unclear what you're asking" причин закрытия

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, локализация, причины-закрытия

Причины для закрытия:

- unclear what you're asking
- too broad

в текущем переводе выглядят слишком похоже:

- необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса
- необходимо конкретизировать вопрос

Comment: Используемые сейчас варианты обсуждались тут: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/545/181472

Comment: @NickVolynkin: да, видно что смешали название причины закрытия (категорию) с объяснением что дальше делать. Мой вопрос обсуждает только сами названия (что они слишком похожи). Для людей, которые дальше названия не читают, я оставил текущие рекомендации к действию в предложенных вариантах (иначе: "всеобъемлющий" и "непонятна суть вопроса" были хорошими названиями категорий)

Comment: Мне нравятся причины с объяснениями. Только "необходимо" хотел бы убрать, канцелярит это и смысла не добавляет.

Comment: Подробная причина полезна не только автору вопроса, но и закрывающим. Вот "опросник" кратко назван и без инструкции - и им пользуются при любом случае.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: как написано по ссылке, которую Вы привели, проблема была что *слишком подробно* было описано, что делать.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вариант перевода ([@avp предложил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1499/%d0%a3%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-too-broad-%d0%b8-unclear-what-youre-asking-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f/1509#comment4280_1500)):

- вопрос неясен: необходимо уточнить подробности
- вопрос слишком широк: необходимо конкретизировать

Comment: Вроде победитель есть, предлагаю принять и писать Nicolas.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: не знаю нужно ли и как  Nicolas Chabanovsky♦ пинговать по поводу обновления перевода (эти фразы и [в справке](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) и в интерфейсе в причинах закрытия присутствуют, может ещё где).

Comment: поскольку они присутствуют в справке, то обязательно нужно его задействовать. Напишу в чате.

Comment: Прошло полтора месяца, и до сих пор ничего не изменилось

Comment: @Oceinic: [попробуйте в чате спросить](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462)

Answer (score 1):

Вариант перевода:

- вопрос неясен: необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса
- вопрос слишком широк: необходимо конкретизировать вопрос

Comment: IMHO слова "вопроса" и "вопрос" в конце лучше выбросить.

Comment: @avp заходите проголосовать за  вариант без "вопросов".

Answer (score 1):

Что если перейти от безличных наречий к конкретным инструкциям?

- вопрос неясен, уточните подробности
- вопрос слишком широк, конкретизируйте его

А то, "вам необходимо - вы и уточняйте".

Comment: Вы посмотрите на контекст (нажмите на кнопку "закрыть") -- там формат: причина закрытия (кратко), затем что делать чтобы исправить. На английском  “too broad” и “unclear what you're asking” это **полные** причины закрытия -- предложенные варианты это перевод этих фраз.

Comment: Да, я видел англоязычные формулировки причин. На мой взгляд, "too broad" вообще никак не побуждает улучшить вопрос. Цель этих строк - не только объяснить причину закрытия, но и помочь улучшить и переоткрыть вопрос.

Comment: @jfs я даже готов добавить к формулировке "пожалуйста", если это повысит конверсию процентов на десять.

Comment: это название категории — как улучшить дальше расписано, например, вот что за **too broad** идёт: *"There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs."*

Comment: Мне нравится этот вариант. По-моему, длинное объяснение в конце большинство не читает, т. к. tldr. Поэтому начальная фраза должна быть достаточно хлёсткой и сразу объяснять, в чём дело и что требуется. Императив очень к месту. А аутисты наподобие меня дочитают и хвост.

Answer (score -1):

Вариант перевода (оставить как есть):

- необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса
- необходимо конкретизировать вопрос