# С какой формулировкой закрывать вопросы о переводе с языка на язык?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Дорогие коллеги, у нас в последнее время разгорелись дискуссии о том, какие вопросы следует закрывать, а какие — нет. Мы, судя по всему, не можем решить проблему сразу и в целом, поэтому давайте попробуем решать её по частям.

Итак, маленькая, частная проблема. В последнее время я замечал несколько вопросов примерно такого характера:

> Мне нужно написать программу на C++, которая вводит с консоли список фамилий школьников и их рост, и выясняет, сколько из них имеют рост выше среднего арифметического. Вот программа на Паскале, которая делает это:
>
> *(Следует более-менее правильный код на Паскале. Можно считать, что код решает данную задачу.)*
>
> Я ни в зуб ногой в языке C++, и уж точно не собираюсь его учить, чтобы сдать эту проклятую лабу. Переведите мне, пожалуйста, код с Паскаля на C++!

Мне кажется, что этот вопрос должен быть удалён. Но по какой причине? На текущий момент валидные причины закрытия такие:

- *Дубликат.* Не подходит, если это *первый* студент из группы, который пришёл к нам. Остальные ещё набегут.
- *Необходимо уточнить подробности вопроса.* Не подходит, в вопросе всё кристально ясно.
- *Необходимо конкретизировать вопрос.* Снова не подходит, конкретнее вопроса не придумаешь.
- *Необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать однозначно верный ответ.* Опять-таки не подходит: любая правильная программа, решающая это задание, представляет собой очевидно и однозначно верный ответ.
- *Не по теме.* Это многообещающая опция. Посмотрим, какие у неё есть подпункты.

  - *Вопросы-опросники запрещены.* Не подходит, вопрос предельно конкретен.
  - *Не воспроизводится или опечатка.* Да нет же!
  - *Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой...* Мимо, автору не нужно отлаживать код, ему нужен готовый, отлаженный код.
  - *В сети Stack Exchange есть другой сайт, более подходящий для этого вопроса.* Нет, вряд ли у нас есть сайт «сделаем вашу лабу».
  - *Кастомная причина.* Это единственное, что может подойти.

Но давайте всё же подумаем, какая может быть эта кастомная причина. Вопрос сам по себе находится на грани между разрешёнными и запрещёнными вопросами.

Если бы вопрос был о переводе *одной* конкретной конструкции («как правильно закодировать Паскалевский `RECORD` с `CASE`'ами на C#?»), этот вопрос, несомненно, имел бы ценность. Но здесь требуется перевести всю программу.

Если бы задача сама по себе была бы интересна хоть кому-нибудь ещё (кроме одногруппников), вопрос был бы нормальным. Но этот вопрос по моему мнению бесполезен для всех. Мне сложно представить себе ответ, который мог бы хоть чем-то помочь любому участнику *как программисту*, не как студенту. Хуже того, правильный ответ на неё **вреден**, так как ставит в заведомо худшие условия *честных* студентов по сравнению с ленивыми и нечестными.

(Единственный потенциально интересный ответ, который я усматриваю — это большой, развёрнутый ответ о том, как же правильно переводить программы с Паскаля на C++, с освещением тонкостей семантики обоих языков. Такой ответ *не будет* принят автором вопроса (ведь ему надо просто готовый код), но наверняка будет заплюсован. И правильный *вопрос* для такого ответа — «как переводить программы с Паскаля на C++».)

Если бы задача имела практическую ценность, это спасло бы вопрос. Но здесь задача специфически-бесполезная, как и большинство учебных задач. Очень сложно представить себе человека, у которого такая задача возникнет в процессе работы, и который за такой конкретикой придёт искать на StackOverflow.

Вопрос даже не принесёт пользы автору! Он не сделает автора более хорошим программистом, лишь позволит ему, получив незаслуженную оценку, и дальше не учиться. То есть по сути принесёт вред.

---

Мне кажется, из возможных причин закрытия самой подходящей была бы удалённая с английского SO причина «Too Localized». Она, насколько я понимаю, означает «вопрос неинтересен никому, кроме автора», но в более вежливой формулировке. Я читал [обсуждение](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154/154101) того, *почему* причина «Too Localized» была удалена. Насколько я понял, предпосылок для этого было две:

- Причина неправильно применялась. Например, слово «localized» понимали как обозначение специфической географической проблемы, и закрывали проблему [*Turkey Test*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/797043/276994) как «Too localized, Turkey is anyway another end of the world». Но это мне кажется следствием плохой, неоднозначной *формулировки* причины закрытия, а не того, что сама причины закрытия плоха.
- Для вопросов, закрываемых по этой причине, можно найти другую, валидную причину закрытия. Это не подходит для нашего случая — я перебрал все действующие причины закрытия.

---

Итак, спасибо всем, кто дочитал до сюда. Я бы хотел вынести на обсуждение следующие четыре конкурирующие предложения.

1. Возродить у нас опцию закрытия «Too Localized» с хорошей, понятной формулировкой, и закрывать подобные вопросы по этой причине.
2. Ввести узкую формулировку «домашнее задание, которое кроме автора никому не нужно», и закрывать подобные вопросы по этой причине.
3. Сформулировать чёткую и валидную причину, по которой такие вопросы нужно закрывать (но не одну из первых двух).
4. Не закрывать такие вопросы вовсе в надежде, что кто-то сможет дать хороший ответ.

Comment: Склоняюсь к самому последнему варианту. Может и найдется одногруппник  (вот ему-то это будет полезно), который ответит и постарается *тут* это сделать *хорошо* (иначе наполучает минусов).

Comment: @avp: Мне хотелось бы тогда ещё настроить постоянных участников на то, что отвечать на такие вопросы кодом неодногруппнику должно быть _стыдно_. Потому что тем самым поощряется лень и неадекватное оценивание студентов. Студент, который задаёт такой вопрос, по-хорошему должен получить заслуженную двойку.

Comment: Каноничный ответ на просьбу перевода из Pascal в C++ это использование препроцессора `#define begin { #define end }` и.т.д. с сохранением оригинального кода автора, но даже таким образом это лень делать.

Comment: А что насчёт объёма кода? Если, допустим, автор предоставил код из 1-2 строк (весьма сомнительно для учебного задания, где так мало не бывает, но всё же), который быстрее переделать, чем попытаться что-то донести до автора, - стоит ли и этот вопрос закрывать? А если нет, то где черта между "можно перевести" и "закрывать"?

Comment: @Regent: Это обсуждается в вопросе: «Если бы вопрос был о переводе _одной_ конкретной конструкции». Но меня интересует именно случай достаточно длинной программы. (Впрочем, если у вас есть предложение насчёт критериев по длине, пишите ответ!)

Comment: @Regent: В любом случае, мне подход «проще дать, чем объяснить, почему нет» не нравится, т. к. он поощряет нежелание разобраться и прикидывание шлангом.

Comment: А ещё, может быть покатит «Not your personal army?»

Comment: @igumnov на боярском наречии хороший код был.

Comment: @Nick Гiмназiстъ нѣ разумѣтъ в крѣсты окаянныѣ

Comment: Вот ещё один вопрос на ту же тему: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/465650/10105

Comment: Судя по количеству требований (увы, уже и не просьб, а просто "надо перевести..." - и так и слышится щелчок кнута...) перевода, воз и ныне там...

Comment: @Harry: Ну раз ничего не поменялось на сайте, результат тоже не меняется. (ваас_безумие.джпг)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Причина проблемы кроется в принципиально неразрешимом противоречии, лежащем в основе системы сайтов Stack Exchange.

Пытаясь исправить одну крайность (крайний снобизм профессионалов в "старых" форумах и ньюсгруппах), создатели сети SE ударились в другую - стремление вытереть нос каждому несчастному, осилившему регистрацию и форму добавления вопроса.

В итоге получилось неразрешимое противоречие: с одной стороны мы декларируем ресурс, как источник знаний для тех, кто приходит через поиск. С другой - культивируем запредельную толерантность и в итоге плодим миллионы мусорных вопросов с не менее мусорными ответами. По факту, моя оценка "большого" SO является такой: ресурс удобен для неспециалистов. Когда я ищу ответ на вопрос в какой-либо смежной области, в которой не являюсь специалистом, обычно ответ меня устраивает. Но если я натыкаюсь на ответ в области, где понимаю немного больше, у меня волосы встают дыбом.

Я думаю, что отцы-основатели давно в курсе этого, но проект уже давно превратился из визионерского в коммерческий, и пока он приносит деньги, никого (из администрации) разрешение этого противоречия волновать не будет. А если будет - то *в противоположном ключе*: миллионы мусорных вопросов - это трафик. А относительно небольшое собрание качественных ответов - это тоже, в общем, трафик... но не такой вкусный. Нет пользовательского фактора. Нет глубины просмотра. Нет того количества одновременных пользователей...

Поэтому такого рода вопросы будут возникать всегда, но никакого приемлемого ответа на них получить не удастся. Следует понимать, что мета сайт - это не площадка для принятия решений, а площадка для выпуска пара. Очередной искатель справедливости задаст вопрос,  ему ответят очень положительно... Но всё останется по-прежнему.

Если же всё же притвориться, что мы не знаем правил игры, и попробовать ответить на этот вопрос, то да - я согласен с предложением, что "too localized" должно присутствовать в списке причин закрытия. Ответ на вопрос, "Скольким людям поможет решение данной проблемы" обычно понятен интуитивно, и может являться универсальным критерием.

Следует понимать, что если сейчас наличие такой опции не слишком актуально, то с ростом популярности ресурса он будет привлекать все больше и больше бездельников и халявщиков. "Большой" SO сейчас попросту захлебывается в их вопросах.

Comment: Может быть тогда предлóжите качественную русскоязычную формулировку для Too Localized на русском? Как показывает практика, отточенность формулировки очень важна (и эта самая неотточенность привела к отказу от использования Too Localizied). У меня, к сожалению, не хватает фантазии и изобретательности.

Comment: Про вытерание носов: я слышал с точностью до наоборот: что SO закрывает слишком много вопросов, что нельзя задать вопрос, чтобы тебя не заминусовали сразу итд.  Про мусорные ответы: это наивная точка зрения, которая игнорирует факт, что не существует источников знаний, создаваемых пользователями, где бы большинство контента не было бы мусором для соответствующего специалиста.

Comment: Теории заговоров не нужно привлекать. Если у вас есть конкретные идеи, которые могут улучшить распространение полезной информации, предлагайте. Похожее обсуждение: [Ресурс из базы знаний для специалистов превращается в консультационный пункт новичков](http://goo.gl/dpbpr7).

Comment: @jfs дело в том, что я не слышал, а *видел*...

Comment: @Ипатьев: Вы не могли *видеть*, что **каждому** "несчастному" нос вытирают -- это не соответствует действительности в прямом и переносном смысле. А так, конечно, для кого-то SO слишком либерален (достаточно на Meta.SO зайти), для кого-то слишком строг -- как свидетельствуют отдельные блоги. Поэтому если Вы видите *конкретные* проблемы, то вместо соблазнительного дешёвого цинизма, попробуйте предложить *конкретные* пути улучшения (если есть желание).

Comment: @VladD: *Может быть тогда предлóжите качественную русскоязычную формулировку для Too Localized на русском?* — что-нибудь вроде «ответ может быть полезен лишь автору вопроса», «ответ на вопрос вряд ли будет полезен кому-либо ещё» и т.п. // лучше, наверно, вынести на голосование: наверняка кто-нибудь придумает лучшую формулировку.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: Целью этого вопроса было выяснить, в частности, не нужна ли нам новая причина закрытия. Если по результатам обсуждения окажется, что да, и эта причина будет именно too localized, тогда будет иметь смысл открывать дискуссию. Подождём ещё немного.

Answer (score 8):

Осторожно, [нытье](/questions/tagged/%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c%d0%b5)!

Зайдите на страницу с [самыми популярными вопросами на MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/popular?show=alltime&sort=hot&pageSize=50). Что мы там видим про причины закрытий? Да знаменитый пост "[Can we please have the “Lacks Minimal Understanding” close reason back?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/257868/can-we-please-have-the-lacks-minimal-understanding-close-reason-back)" с оценкой в 650, вот что!

Сообщество в массе своей требует причину для закрытия вопросов <s>"Ты идиот и не лечишься"</s> "У вас проблемы с пониманием базовых вещей".

Для чего нужна причина? Да потому что есть вопросы, суть которых кристально чисто ясна, они не слишком общие, они не дубликаты, они не спорные, они не просят сторонние ресурсы, они о программировании, и в них нет опечаток. Они просто написаны человеком, который не понимает задачу и не пытается её понять, он просто хочет готовое решение. И нет, домашними работами это не ограничивается.

В том посте было предложено несколько решений:

1. Пользоваться причиной "Приведите минимальный воспроизводимый пример с указанием на конкретную ошибку", если это возможно. Эта причина не только про отладку, эта причина в первую очередь про отсутствие [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (MCVE в терминологии СО).
2. Добавить размытую причину в духе "Это не вопрос, который задал бы программист-энтузиаст" (СО ведь "для профессионалов и энтузиастов" в официальной формулировке).
3. Нацепить фальшивые улыбки на физиономии и встречать всех лодырей и двоечников с лозунгом "Be Nice". Делать вид, что развёрнутый ответ с объяснениями кому-то нужен, а на деле надеяться на охотников за кармой, которые готовы отвечать на любые вопросы ради вожделенных плюсиков.
4. Минусовать.

Угадайте, что было выбрано в итоге? Правильно, оставить всё как есть. В связи с этим я не верю, что даже у нашего обожаемого предводителя Николаса хватит силы убеждения, чтобы повлиять на подобное глобальное решение в компании. Он уже говорил, что сотрудники смотрят на него косо, когда он предлагает добавить больше пяти причин "оффтопика".

В связи с вышесказанным предлагаю закатать губу и пользоваться тем, что есть.

Comment: Хе! Можно ведь воспользоваться нашей свободой от решений en.SO и таки ввести это правило. Но нужна подходящая формулировка.

Comment: Нашёл в комментариях две хорошие формулировки: «We are here to help you solve your problem; we will not freely write or debug code for you. Please don't abuse our generosity» и «Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Try including attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See How can I ask better questions on Server Fault? for further guidance.»

Comment: Хорошая формулировка не должна запрещать годные вопросы наподобие «как работает `using`», например. Хотя в нём тоже как бы формально говоря lack of minimal understanding. В этом сложность и необходимость правильного подбора фразы (и поэтому я решил начать с конкретной темы).

Comment: @VladD Да невозможно подобрать магическую фразу, которая решит все проблемы. Во-первых, потому что каждый волен интерпретировать её как угодно (см. существующие причины для закрытия, собственно). Во-вторых, потому что единого взгляда на подобные вопросы не существует, споры о том, хороший вопрос или плохой, будут вечно. А если кто-то считает вопрос плохим, то причина для закрытия всегда найдётся.

Comment: Я не настолько наивен, чтобы думать, что хорошая формулировка решит все проблемы. Но например «too localized» была явно misleading (ка это по-русски?). Или например формулировка «д/з» будет косвенно означать, что _любое_ д/з у нас не катит, хотя мы на текущий момент считаем, что плохо лишь то д/з, которое не интересно ни по какому другому критерию. Так что хорошая формулировка нужна лишь чтобы **уменьшить** количество неправильных срабатываний, но не отменяет необходимость следить за адекватностью применения. Модерация — это не состояние, это процесс. :)

Comment: не нужно быть кровожадным и пытаться покарать людей, которые не демонстрируют попыток решения задачи. Если я имею ту же задачу, то меня интересует ответ, а не сколько усилий автор вопроса затратил. 90+% посетителей на SO с поисковиков: если вопрос полезен -- его следует оставить.

Comment: @jfs Вы как раз приверженец пункта №3. Знаем, понимаем.

Comment: @Discord: неверно и подло приписывать эти взгляды мне.

Comment: Я бы всё же не использовал слово «кровожадный» — это явная манипуляция. Студенты, которые приходят сюда, чтобы за них решили их задания — вовсе не безобидные жертвы. Несчастными и проигравшими в данной ситуации являются будущие пользователи их программ.

Comment: @jfs: Оставаясь в рамках оригинального вопроса и не расширяя его до всех д/з: ответ на рассматриваемый в ОП вопрос _никому_ не полезен. Об этом явно говорится в ОП.

Answer (score 4):

[Как мы с Вами уже обсуждали](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0/233#comment438_233) такие вопросы можно оставить открытыми, если они могут быть для кого-то ещё полезны (например, если взять и заменить весь код на Паскале на простой русский язык, который с той же точностью задаёт задачу -- будет ли такой вопрос полезен ещё кому-либо кроме автора? Если да, то вопрос не следует закрывать (при наличии адекватного описания задачи на русском языке). Или если вопрос содержит распространённую идиому на языке Паскаль, которую было бы интересно перевести на С++ -- то есть если другие люди, которые переносят программы с Паскаля на С могут с той же проблемой столкнуться, то также следует оставить вопрос).

**В противном случае следует минусовать и/или закрывать, используя разные причины в зависимости от конкретного вопроса. В итоге подобные вопросы будут удалены спустя какое-то время.**

Ваш пример с Паскалем, я бы минусовал за отсутствие попыток решения со стороны автора или закрыл бы как ["too broad"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1499/23044) -- C++ слишком большой язык, чтобы в одном ответе его изложить (если автору необходимо объяснять как работать с wstring, vector<>, class/struct).

Автору можно оставить комментарий, что если он знает Паскаль, но не знает C++, то ему следует разбить его проблему на подзадачи (конкретизировать вопрос), которые были бы полезны другим людям, например:

- как напечатать Юникод (многоязычные фамилии могут быть) в консоль на С++
- как найти среднее арифметическое в С++ (арифметика с float (representation error: `1/3+1/3+1/3!=1`), алгоритм типа [`math.fsum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.fsum) (precision loss))

> @jfs: Оставаясь в рамках оригинального вопроса и не расширяя его до всех д/з: ответ на рассматриваемый в ОП вопрос никому не полезен. Об этом явно говорится в ОП. – VladD

Ваш вопрос: *"С какой формулировкой закрывать вопросы о переводе с языка на язык?"* -- не все вопросы из данной категории бесполезны (это мне кажется очевидным, но я могу подробней объяснить если необходимо).

Про конкретный пример в вопросе [я уже говорил](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1575/%d0%a1-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba#comment4493_1583), но для ясности решил выделить жирным это место в ответе (см. выше). Повторюсь: если автор не демонстрирует усилий решить проблему и если вопрос бесполезен для других участников, то голосуйте "против" как это явно указано в подсказке. Это достаточно для большинства таких вопросов. **Новые причины закрытия не нужны** и [будут вредны как практика уже показала](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/23044).

> Я бы всё же не использовал слово «кровожадный» — это явная манипуляция. Студенты, которые приходят сюда, чтобы за них решили их задания — вовсе не безобидные жертвы. Несчастными и проигравшими в данной ситуации являются будущие пользователи их программ.

[Ещё раз](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1575/%d0%a1-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5-%d1%81-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba#comment4489_1581): состояние ума автора вопроса (его невинность) не имеет значения, если это не меняет полезности вопроса. Автор может быть полным лентяем и плохим студентом, но если вопрос полезен для других участников, то следует сознательно сопротивляться стремлению "наказать" автора, закрывая его вопрос.

Если вопрос бесполезен, то не важно задал его честный/нечестный человек.
Если вопрос полезен, то не важно задал его честный/нечестный человек.

Не хорошо закрывать вопрос *только потому что вам не нравится моральных облик автора*. Оценивать следует только содержимое самого вопроса.

Справедливости ради, кто задаёт вопрос может иметь значение, на то как этот вопрос *эволюционирует во времени*: например, если автор может улучшить вопрос, то я иногда вместо того чтобы сразу голосовать "против", оставляю комментарий. И только потом, если не вижу улучшений, то минусую -- формально следует сразу минусовать, но чтобы не деморализовывать новичков, откладываю голосование.

Я понимаю (но не разделяю точку зрения), что многие люди считают положительным результатом уже само наказание плохих людей, даже если это ничто другое не меняет. В конечном итоге, полезные вопросы задаются многократно и мы можем подождать пока автор с правильным моральным обликом появится прежде чем разрешать отвечать на вопрос.

Не следует пытаться карать людей, если это не несёт пользы (делает текущий вопрос более полезным, предотвращает появление бесполезных вопросов, направляет ограниченное внимание знатоков на более достойные вопросы итд).

Comment: (1) Я специально привёл такой пример, который совершенно точно никому не может быть полезен. Если кому-то нужно узнать о тонкостях семантики массивов там и там, из перевода кода на C++ всё равно это не будет понятно.

Comment: (2) Я не согласен с «Too broad» = «необходимо конкретизировать вопрос». Вопрос _предельно_ конкретен.

Comment: @VladD: Поэтому я привёл абзац, начинающийся "Ваш пример с Паскалем".

Comment: И автор _не_ хочет, чтобы ему растолковали, как переводить те или иные конструкции. Он вообще не хочет выучиться программировать. Он хочет, чтобы за него выполнили домашнее задание. И он это обычно в таких случаях совершенно явно указывает в вопросе или в комментариях. (И я указал это в вопросе тоже.)

Comment: @VladD: [перевод на русский этой причины закрытия был испорчен.](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1499/23044) Если Вы почитаете оригинальную причину, то ясно что она применима -- если полезный ответ слишком большой получается, то вопрос "too broad" -- присутствует фраза "isolate an issue" -- если человек не знает С++, то кол-во возможных неясностей безгранично. Если Вы не хотите закрывать как "too broad", то достаточно проголосовать "против" (вопрос не полезен и отсутствуют усилия) -- если никто не ответит на вопрос, то он будет автоматически удалён.

Comment: Ну, давайте я всё же повторюсь. Ответ, который имеет в виду автор, не слишком большой, 15-20 строк на C++. Он не знает языка и ему не нужен tutorial. Ему не нужен полезный для других ответ, такой ответ не решит проблему автора. И он по условию обсуждения явно об этом заявляет. Получается странный диалог. ТС: «Дайте код!» Я: «мы в голове у себя переделали ваш вопрос из «дайте код» в «объясните, как писать такой код», и в этой новой формулировке вопрос плохой, и мы его закрываем». Согласитесь, абсурдно выглядит.

Comment: @VladD: я не против, если кто-то эти 10-15 строчек напишет -- такие вопросы мне попадаются не слишком часто (обе опции: минусование, закрытие бесполезного вопроса как "too broad" вполне достаточны — я не помню, когда последний раз приходилось вторую опцию использовать)

Comment: Re: ваше обновление. Возможно, заголовок вопроса недостаточно чётко сформулирован. Но это и неважно. В самом вопросе чётко и однозначно поставлено условие, что рассматриваемый гипотетический вопрос ленивого студента **не полезен** никому. Я не против оставлять вопросы, которые могут быть кому-либо полезны, но речь идёт о вопросах, ответ на который бесполезен. (Я сознательно отбрасываю «хрупкие предположения» о совпадениях формулировки вопроса с реальной задачей с вероятностью меньше миллионной доли процента.)

Comment: Мне кажется, ваш ответ не вполне на мой вопрос, а на вопрос о закрытии _вообще всех возможных_ вопросов о переводе с языка на язык. Мой вопрос лишь о плохих вопросах.

Comment: @VladD: (1) я уверен, что Вы понимаете разницу между одним примером и целым классом вопросов. Если бы Вы использовали: *"С какой формулировкой закрывать **бесполезные** вопросы о переводе с языка на язык?"* заголовок, то я бы дал бы другой ответ. Если бы Вы в теле вопроса *явно* бы указали, что вы рассматриваете **только бесполезные** вопросы, то я бы дал бы другой ответ. Один плохой пример не означает, что вся категория бесполезна (2) *"вероятностью меньше миллионной доли процента"* -- это неверное утверждение (даже ваш пример легко разбивается на два полезных вопроса (см. пример в ответе)).

Comment: (1) Если бы я спросил конкретно о **бесполезных** вопросах, я бы этим самым подтолкнул отвечающих к ответу «с формулировкой „бесполезен‟». Я старался не навязывать «очевидно правильный ответ». (2) Я не вполне понял, о каком примере из ответа вы говорите.

Comment: @VladD: (1) вместо слова "бесполезный" (которое уже присутствует в интерфейсе), можно "плохой" использовать (которое более расплывчатое значение может иметь), чтобы не создавать ненужные ассоциации и не подталкивать к определённому ответу. Это суть моего аргумента не меняет (категория всё равно может содержать как "плохие" так и "хорошие" вопросы) (2) поищите "разбить его проблему на подзадачи" в ответе.

Comment: Мне кажется, что подход, который вы предлагаете — игнорировать вопрос автора, и выдумать за него несвязанный вопрос, который нам покажется полезен. Кроме того, по условиям ТС **не способен** скомбинировать элементарные задачи в готовое решение, поэтому преобразование вопроса по сути сделает ответы бесполезными для автора. Из двух вариантов — закрыть вопрос или переделать его так, чтобы он был бесполезен для автора — первый кажется мне честным, хоть и нелицеприятным («за вас домашку мы не сделаем»), второй — издевательским («вот вам ответ, который поможет кому-то другому, но не вам»).

Comment: @VladD: я этого не предлагаю (я упомянул разбиение на подзадачи, чтобы опровергнуть Ваше ошибочное утверждение о "вероятностью меньше миллионной доли процента" -- если задача состоит из всего 2 подзадач, то есть одна подзадача полезна 1%, а другая 0.2%, то целая подзадача **гораздо** более вероятна, чем  миллионная доля процента -- гугл не ищёт **буквальное** совпадение вопросов). Многие полезные вопросы можно разбить на ещё более общие чаще встречающиеся подзадачи..

Comment: ..не обязательно, чтобы вопрос буквально совпадал -- посмотрите на дубликаты -- вопросы могут иметь сильно различающиеся формулировки, а ответы при этом одинаковые с точностью до тривиальных (не имеющих отношения к оригинальному вопросу) изменений.