# Что делать с домашней работой и ленью?

Tags: обсуждение, статус-отклонено

Приветствую.

Рискую навлечь гнев Всевышних-банмолотодержащих, но подниму опять этот вопрос:

**Почему такая лояльность к вопросам учеников и лентяев?**

Как [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643899/207618) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643908/207618) или [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/224863/207618) (куча этого добра, только копни).

---

**Лень** - благо только иногда (стало лень носить камни - изобрели тележку, а потом робота, чтобы даже не ходить).
Основную часть времени - это зло, зло, с которым нужно бороться, а не поощрять.

Она заключается не только в отсутствии желания поиска (даже по SO), а фундаментально изучать предмет.
Тут всё плохо - приходишь, даёшь ТЗ, говоришь [волшебное слово "Бегом, холопы!"](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36260805#36260805) и реподобыватели резво отвечают.

*Противодействия:*
Минусы не останавливают ни первых (спросил - ушёл), ни вторых (из-за мягкой политики к минусам (-5 === 1)).
Закрытие - неэффективно по тем же причинам.
Да и искать дубли затруднительно (если только вчера не видел такой же вопрос).

*Ценность для сайта:*
Нулевая; задают те же яйца, только в другом вопросе, который вроде и не дубль, но содержит алгоритм решения.
Да и их задавать надо учебнику, а мы, как не старайся, не учебник.
Плюс - воспитывать поколение быдлокодеров, которые привыкли что развиваться не нужно, ведь всегда есть те, кто ответит.

---

**Домашняя работа** - это, в первую очередь, разминка для ума.
Задачи, которые им дают, не являются неразрешимыми или действительно сложными (ОК, последние курсы не берём, хотя даже там всё банально и просто), поэтому решать их авторы не хотят опять же из-за лени/систематического прогула/незаинтересованности в предмете/вставь своё.

Из [справки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):

> Домашние задания надо выполнять самостоятельно. Если у вас возник вопрос по домашнему заданию, не просите его сделать за вас. Задайте конкретный вопрос о проблеме, которую вы не можете решить. Программирование — это то, в чём надо разбираться самому, либо не заниматься им вовсе. Если для вас программирование — лишний предмет в учебной программе, есть сайты и люди на этих сайтах, выполняющие задания за материальное вознаграждение. Здесь предлагать выполнить работу за вас и наоборот — моветон.

*Противодействия*:
Так же, как и с ленью, но не работают по тем же причинам.

*Ценность для сайта:*
Ну... сборник ответов на вопросы, которые не должны быть обществом отвечены, ради блага обучения автора и остальных, кому задали/зададут эту задачку.
Радует (?) только то, что новые ученики не будут их искать, а зададут новый, такой же.
Плюс - там часто бывают искусственные ограничения, поэтому их ценность в жизни сомнительна.

---

Безусловно, нельзя всё подгонять под одну модераторскую метлу - бывают и там хорошие вопросы, но это исключение.
Только не надо про политику большого SO, у нас свой мир, с менталитетом и особенностями.

Тема для решений, для <s>срача</s> обсуждения, пожалуйста, используйте [чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

Благодарю за внимание.

### UPD:

Добавили [причину закрытия](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5043/207618).
Не победа, но уже что-то.

Comment: Вопрос по js'у (который в первом примере) хороший и описывает классическую ошибку. Чем он тебе не угодил?

Comment: Тем, что это основы взаимодействия JS и DOM. А вместо учебника, автор пошёл сюда.

Comment: @Other тогда надо запрещать вообще все простые вопросы (их авторы, очевидно, просто ленятся гуглить!, что зло! ЗЛО!). И заодно запретить отвечать авторам любым кодом, если они его собрались использовать в реальном приложении - вы им код бесплатно - а они за него деньги получат!

Comment: Вопрос уже обсуждался ни раз. Как мне кажется, размышляя согласно изложенному в вопросе мы допускаем ошибку понимания того, для кого мы публикуются ответы на сайте. Ответы на сайте публикуются не для автора вопроса, а для коллег, которые столкнуться с подобной задачей в будущем и будут искать ответ в поисковике. Таким образом, существует два критерия фильтрации вопросов: (1) соответствует ли вопрос правилам сайта; (2) был ли этот вопрос задан ранее. _Критерия «леность» не существует_!

Comment: Если мы хотим, чтобы ресурс был полезен для сообщества программистов, то к этому вопросу нужно отнестись очень внимательно. Мне кажется, это критически важный вопрос, который нуждается в решении. Предыдущие обсуждения, судя по текущей ситуации, решения не принесли.

Comment: Сейчас ситуация на мой взгляд такова: 1) программист (профессионал) имеет очень мало шансов получить полезный ответ на свой реальный вопрос; 2) Студенты, которым лень делать домашку, читать учебник или искать в гугле, задают вопросы; 3) Какие-то люди по какой-то причине очень хотят заработать репутацию и сутками напролет отвечают на вопросы студентов, пересказывая азы языка, часто не имея хорошего знания предмета и порой даже не понимая смысла слов, которые пишут; 4) программисту (профессионалу) это не интересно, и он перестает сюда заходить;

Comment: 5) Когда программист (профессионал) задает вопрос, он не может получить ответа, потому что предыдущий программист (профессионал) сюда больше не заходит.

Comment: Когда мы говорим о полезности ресурса, надо уточнять - подразумеваемая полезность - она для кого и для чего? Ресурс помогает студентам сдавать курсовые? Да. А помогает ли он этим росту качества сообщества, если сообщество пополняется бывшими студентами, ни разу не потрудившимися почитать учебники или посмотреть свою программу под отладчиком?

Comment: В качестве аргумента в пользу ответов на вопросы ленивых студентов в предыдущем обсуждении прозвучала такая мысль: "если ответ помогает кому-то сэкономить время, он полезен". Но если время тратится на учёбу, на тренировки - экономить это время за счет чужой работы - вредно для обучающегося.

Comment: @m.vokhm, ресурс (подобно С++) полон противоречий. Наверное, вопросы  было бы полезно разделить по крайней мере на 2 части (обе были бы полезны и востребованы), но никто на это не пойдет.

Comment: @m.vokhm, `экономить это время за счет чужой работы - вредно для обучающегося` -- не всегда, некоторые люди лучше всего обучаются на примерах

Comment: Могу сказать по себе - в конце прошлого года, когда получил приглашение по e-mail, пару месяцев чувствовал изрядный энтузиазм, отвечал на вопросы. Но через пару месяцев интерес пропал. Насколько моих вопросов ответов не получили, читать дурацкие вопросы стало скучно, а ответы на них - порой больно. Веры в полезность и большое будущее этого сайта сильно поубавилось. В результате месяца три вообще уже не заходил сюда.

Comment: @m.vokhm, если на вопрос быстро не ответили, скорее всего без обновлений (вытягивающих вопрос на верх) его просто никто не увидит.

Comment: Несколько странно видеть метку [meta-tag:обсуждение] и фразу "для обсуждения, пожалуйста, используйте чат."

Comment: @alexolut, заведомо ясно что будет (и была уже) куча сообщений. А единственное, где это возможно - чат.

Comment: Чтобы не повторять аргументы, на которые уже отвечали неоднократно, посмотрите популярное обсуждение [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/231/23044) или то что прямо сейчас в "важно" категории на Мете висит [Допустимы ли вопросы, где подразумевается работа за автора?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4882/23044).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Работа за автора](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/231/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b0%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Comment: @jfs ни разу не дубликат. Там рассматривались вопросы, похожие на задания по информатике - а тут речь идет о постах, которые именно заданиями и являются.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1575

Comment: @PavelMayorov: если бы вы прочитали [мой ответ](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/233/23044), то вы бы узнали: 1- что если *вопрос полезный*, то не имеет значения является ли он заданием или нет. Что не ясно в факте, что 95%+ SO траффика из поисковиков? (кто автор не важно, если ответы помогают многим) 2- что раньше уже существовали похожие причины закрытия, что многолетняя *практика показала*, что введение подобных причин закрытия ведёт только к одному результату: **полезные вопросы закрываются, а мусор продолжает расти**. Кнопка "закрыть" является плохим инструментом для таких вопросов.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ещё одно предложение, основанное на обсуждении в чате: дополнить список закрытия причиной «Не по теме» → «Не содержит вопроса».

Обоснование: чаще всего такие вопросы содержат лишь дамп задания, и вопрос в них либо отсутствует вовсе, либо чисто формален («как мне выполнить это задание»).

Вопрос формального отличия этого случая от нормального изложения проблемы и финального вопроса «как добиться такого эффекта» остаётся. Просьба предлагать уточнения к формулировке.

Comment: Может что-то типа "Содержит задание вместо вопроса"? Будет как некая параллель с "Ссылка вместо ответа" :)

Comment: Это уже лучше. Правда тогда нытья будет много, наверное.

Comment: Мне нравится, послушаем ещё мнения.

Comment: А как же "для <s>срача</s> обсуждения, пожалуйста, используйте чат." от автора?

Comment: @alexolut: Ну, в идеале хорошо бы, чтобы варианты публиковались в виде ответов, и чтобы за них голосовали.

Comment: @alexolut Сделайте ваше предложение отдельным ответом (еще одним!), чтобы за него можно было голосовать.

Comment: @PavelMayorov на самом деле, обсуждаемый здесь вопрос более широк, чем просто предложение по вариантам для добавления в группу "не по теме", но так уж получилось, что существующие два ответа предлагают по-сути одинаковый подход.

Comment: @alexolut это не просто строчка в группе, это - новый критерий для отбраковки вопросов на сайте. В моем понимании существующие два ответа отличаются принципиально, а не просто деталями. Деталь-то ключевая, в ней вся суть.

Comment: @PavelMayorov я не могу согласиться с Вами. Решение и в моём, и Влада ответах - добавить новую причину в группу "не по теме". Текст этой причины - предполагает дальнейшее обсуждение. И обсуждать его есть смысл только лишь после утверждения сообществом общего решения (вероятно, в отдельном вопросе), которое, повторюсь, одинаково в упомянутых ответах. Новый ответ вполне может подразумевать вообще что-то иное, нежели текст причины.

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Может быть, вы сформулируйте как вам кажется полезным? (Знаю, что это непросто.) И напишите отдельным ответом. Даже одно отличающееся слово может хорошо помочь.

Comment: @VladD зачем? Мне нравится ваша формулировка.

Comment: Зачем дублировать? Для этого же уже есть отличный вариант "непонятна суть вопроса" - непонятно что сам человек спрашивает, с чем просит помощи.

Comment: @Kromster: Суть-то понятна, «сделайте за меня домашку».

Answer (score 1):

[Как мы видим по прошествию времени](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/6205/6), подобную причину начинают использовать не по назначению, закрывая все подряд. Необходимо подумать еще или применить другой подход.

Comment: Идея стоящая, просто формулировка, быть может, подкачала. Просто удалять её - глупо ИМХО.

Comment: @Other Формулировку следует уточнить, да! В текущем виде данная причина закрытия создает огромную нагрузку на модераторов. Поговаривают, что он больше вреда, чем пользы приносят.

Comment: Да, @PashaPash оценил полезность 1 к 9 (на 1 правильную закрывашку 9 неверных). Сформулировать сложно как минимум потому, что тут грань разрешённых вопросов очень близка к тому, с чем боремся. Настолько, что точно и не опишешь. Слишком мягкая политика и желание топа в поисковых системах дают о себе знать.

Comment: @Other не соглашусь. Мы открыты к конкретным прикладным вопросам, которые могут появиться у других разработчиков. Домашка это или нет - не так важно. Важна реальность и прикладная суть вопроса.

Comment: А почему бы сразу ГДЗ по всем курсам институтов не сделать? И книжечку напечатать. Хотя главная проблема не в вопросах, а авторах - формат "Дайте/сделайте" не имеет ни адекватного практического применения, ни смысла отвечать. Придётся закрывать на другие причины, видимо.

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, причем тут домашки вообще? Мы создаем базу знаний. Без вопросов нет ответов. Если студент для лабы хочет узнать как сделать перебор всех файлов в каталоге, подскажите, чем отличается от инженера, решающего ту же задачу? Как вы правильно заметили, главное — практический смысл.

Comment: Домашки - ну так, видимо, идентифицируют класс этих проблем. Повторюсь - я ни разу не против хорошего вопроса с практической ценностью, но я против вопросов, смысл которых: "Я прогулял 3 курса, а теперь требуют написать самообучающегося робота, напишите, будут благодарен" - ни практического смысла (кроме помощи его однокурсникам о_0), ни грамотной задачи (вот вам круг - дорисуйте сову), ни совести :) Убранная причина могла принять удар подобных закрывашек на себя, но теперь и её нет.

Answer (score -4):

На основании цитаты из Cправки про домашнюю работу, приведённой в вопросе, а так же наличии возможности добавить новую (суб-) причину закрытия офтопичных вопросов. О чём [упоминал Nicolas в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=36314933#36314933):

> Кстати, мы можем в раздел не по теме добавить новую причину.

Предлагаю такую причину всё же добавить. Вопрос лишь в удачности формулировки этой причины. Например (не претендует на лучший и единственный вариант):

> Автор не продемонстрировал собственных усилий для решения проблемы

Обычно вопросы, которые подпадают под такую категорию, начинаются со слов "Необходимо", "Нужно", "Сделать", "Написать", "Реализовать" и т.д., т.е. сформулированные как приказ к дальнейшим действиям. Такие слова являются своеобразным маркером подобных вопросов. Текст вопроса скорее всего совпадает дословно с тем текстом задания, которое получил ТС от преподавателя и не содержит более никаких своих мыслей.

В некоторых случаях подобные вопросы тем не менее могут быть интересны. Но так это или нет в любом случае будет решаться голосованием за закрытие или переоткрытие. Если кто-то не желает закрывать подобный вопрос, самый правильный путь, как я считаю, это, помимо выбора пункта "Оставить открытым" в очереди проверок, переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы желание закрыть вопрос убавилось. Т.е. чтобы он стал меньше походить на домашнее задание ленивого студента.

Comment: Мне этот вариант не нравится, потому что вопрос оценивается по субъективному признаку, завязанному на личность автора, а не по объективному критерию, завязанному на качество самого вопроса.

Comment: Категории "старался" - "не старался" допустимы только в детском саду и в начальной школе. Уже с пятого класса оцениваются знания а не усидчивость.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Вы оцениваете весь ответ по одной строчке? Это всего лишь пример. Можно заменить "Автор" на "В сообщении", суть от этого не изменится.

Comment: Я оцениваю конкретную строчку, которую потом могу увидеть в причинах закрытия.

Comment: И от смены "автор" на "в сообщении" и правда мало что изменится - все тот же упор на старания, а не содержание.

Comment: @PavelMayorov содержание так или иначе отражает старания.

Comment: Против. StackOverflow в долгосрочной перспективе старается обезличивать вопросы, игнорировать то, кем вопрос задан и почему. Поэтому редактировать вопросы могут все. Поэтому к голосам за участников (а не их контент) относятся неодобрительно. Закрывать необходимо лишь вопрос, который **плох сам по себе**, а эта причина позволит переводить стрелки на автора, который может по каким-то причинам кому-то не понравиться.

Comment: @D-side я уже объяснял Павлу, что не стоит отождествлять ответ с текстом причины. Вы совершаете ту же ошибку.

Comment: @alexolut как и не стоит отождествлять формулировку вопроса с её сутью, что ответ и предлагает. Если бы формулировка была важна, SE не давал бы возможности редактировать вопросы всем желающим. Я в чате уже указывал на "закрытие из мелкого формализма", когда под якобы-вопросом "решить задачу" скрывается вопрос "как решить задачу?", что стоит исправлять правками и закрывать по уже существующим причинам, если они применимы. Я не вижу необходимости в новой. Т. е. то, как автор сформулировал проблему, это скорее проблема автора, и вопроса, и это не слишком веский повод для закрытия.

Comment: *автора, а не вопроса (очепятка)