# Предлагаю закрывать вопросы с "переводами" как дубликаты

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, закрытие-вопросов

[Вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1575/195342) поднимался, и не раз ... Но каково мнение о таком предложении: написать один раз вопрос с просьбой о переводе, дать ответ, что программы нужно не переводить, а писать свои с нуля, что иначе это совершенно никакой пользы никому не приносит, и закрывать такие вопросы с переводом сразу и безусловно, как дубли. Вопрос закрыт, причина пояснена.

Как сообщество смотрит на такое решение? Набросать-то такой вопрос-ответ я могу и сам, но вот получить потом массу пфе и обвинений в нетолерастности мне что-то очень не хочется.

Но вопросы "переведите мне программу с одного языка на другой" - это, на мой взгляд, еще хуже, чем "напишите мне программу с нуля".

**Update**

Чтоб не писать 2 раза - еще один тип вопросов, который мне представляется столь же плохим, как и просьба перевести - просьба объяснить, как работает некий код. Который означает одно - код откуда-то (с)перт :), и человек планирует выдать его за свой, не понимая, как он работает...

Comment: По-моему, такое уже практиковалось как-то. Я лично закрывал дублем какой-то Pascal -> C++ или что-то около того. Было весело. Можем повторить (ц)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Если будет еще хоть пару голосов "за" - то точно напишу такой вопрос-ответ для закрытия переводов...

Comment: Можно просто ссылку ближайшего переводчика давать :) https://www.online-translator.com/

Comment: Отказывать сходу в просьбе объяснить, как работает какой-то фрагмент кода как-то *не комильфо...*. Просто представил, что самому потребуется разобраться в коде на каком-нибудь rubi (haskell, perl, ...) c целью написать аналогичный скрипт на чем-то более знакомом, а спросить-то нельзя. И мне  эта идея принципиально не понравилась. Может все же лучше старый принцип -- не нравится, пройди мимо?

Comment: @avp Да я так и делаю, просто высказываю свое мнение. Видите ли, вопросы "как это работает" с реально сложным кодом попадались только раза два... Кстати, вы можете задать вопрос - "поясните алгоритм, который реализует этот код" - и это будет принципиальным отличием от "напишите комментарии, что делает каждая строчка этого кода". Нет?

Comment: @Harry, с одной стороны, да. С друугой, бывает, что в целом алгоритм понятен, но не понятно, что делают некоторые строки  на малознакомом языке (как известно, дьявол в деталях). Конечно, можно заняться его изучением, но иногда бывает нужно просто быстро что-то перенести

Comment: @Harry, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/882718/232 как иллюстрация просьбы объяснить  построчно код. (я наверное полчаса потратил, пока догадался)

Comment: @avp Если формализовать - то понятно, что никто не скажет, где начало того конца, которым оканчивается начало :) Но разница между таким кодом и тем, что я имею в виду в вопросе, по-моему, очевидна...

Comment: @Harry, нам с вами очевидна. Но 5 формалистов, которые этого не понимают обычно находятся

Answer (score 16):

При закрытии дублем автоматика удалит вопрос только через 365 дней, в отличие от других причин закрытия, при которых удаление происходит через 9 дней: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/roomba

> Если вопрос был закрыт более 9 дней назад и ...
>
> **был закрыт с причиной отличной от “копия”;**
>
> ... он также будет удален.

Это значит, ваш метод приведет к более медленному удалению мусорных вопросов. Дублями надо закрывать только те вопросы, которые не подпадают под другие причины закрытия.

Так что, пожалуй, не надо. Закрывайте как "необходимо конкретизировать", если участник просит перевести целую программу, эта формулировка вполне подходит. Пусть конкретизирует, что не получается. То, что программы надо писать свои, а не переводить списанное у соседа, само собой разумеется и растолковывать это не входит в задачи сайта.

Comment: Откровенно говоря, у меня в поиске вопросов прошито `is:q intags:mine closed:no score:-2`, так что закрытые вопросы меня не беспокоят :) Но вопрос - наберется ли 5 неравнодушных человек, чтобы закрыть такой вопрос по иной причине?...

Comment: Разве дубля с негативной оценкой не удалит? Из какого пункта описания в справке это следует?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Удалит, но только через 365 дней. Обычные закрытые - через 9. Неточно выразился в ответе.

Answer (score 12):

С одной стороны, это довольно весело и интересно (ещё можно и репки поднять, если общим сообщением не делать). С другой стороны, по аналогичной схеме можно придумать QA для любых других причин закрытия вопросов, например, сразу вспоминается причина с созвучным названием, но о переводе не языка программирования, а языка изложения - "задавайте вопросы на русском или дуйте на enSO". Дальше можно будет создать вопрос-эталон для каких-нибудь спаммерских сообщений с вакансиями и т.п. ...

В такой виде это уже выглядит достаточно абсурдно. Поэтому я, наверное, всё же выскажусь за то, что эталонный вопрос тут не нужен. Надо просто продолжать закрывать как "учебное задание" или "непонятна суть вопроса" и т.д. Всё равно даже если будем закрывать дублем вопросы вряд ли будут иметь хоть какой-то позитивный рейтинг, а без этого рейтинга они просто в очередной момент будут прибиты румбой и преданы забвению. Это не позволит приходить в эталонный ответ из поисковика или при задании очередного вопроса (когда выводится список похожих).

При этом, если я правильно понял, закрытие дублем преследует не только цель дать развёрнутое описание того, что просить переводы не стоит (это по идее может быть отражено на уровне справки или специфичной для сообщества причины, как это сделано сейчас с домашними заданиями), но ещё и ускорение процедуры закрытия, т.к. это сможет делать единолично не только модератор, но и участник с золотой меткой. Иногда быстро закрыть/удалить - это хорошо, когда речь о каком-то явном оффтопе или спаме, но с другой стороны просто закрытые дублем вопросы остаются висеть в списке на главное, а пропадают лишь при достаточном отрицательном рейтинге (вроде бы минус 8, если не ошибаюсь). Понятно, что даже обладатель золотого молота не сможет единолично так обрушить рейтинг вопроса. Т.о. возможно стоит чуть больше раскрыть в вопросе необходимость подхода с дубликатами, если вдруг в моём ответе она интерпретирована неверно.